# Trouple unzipping a 4GB .zip file on CentOS 5.5

Tags: linux, zip, centos-5

I am in the process of moving from a windows to a linux box. I zipped a folder of images on the windows box and ftpd it to the linux box. When I try to `unzip` the file I get:

```
error:  Zip file too big (greater than 4294959102 bytes)
Archive:  gallery.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  gallery.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of gallery or
    gallery.zip, and cannot find gallery.ZIP, period.
```

How can I unzip this file if it's too big?

Comment: Did you zip it on a FAT32 partition?

Comment: I believe it is NTFS

Answer (score 1):

Use a different format like 7z?  Or unzip with p7zip.

Comment: I was going to go for p7zip but didn't find any packages that would work with CentOS (red hat): http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: And I'm sure based on that comment you've gathered I'm a linux noob. :/

Comment: A quick googol for `p7zip rpm` gives me: http://packages.sw.be/p7zip/

Comment: @jyoseph everyone starts as a noob :)